# Can't load .dev website after flushing DNS and clearing cache (works fine on mobile)

Tags: caching, dns, hosting

I just registered a website and having trouble accessing it on a computer. Loads fine on my mobile device.

I've tried flushing my DNS and clearing my chrome cache on Mac and Windows. What's left to do?

Site is a .dev domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/122337/google-dev-domain-strangely-redirects-to-https

Here is the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the dig command in unix based systems to make dns queries. In dig you have an option, `@` to specify the dns server against which you can make the query. See that query is returning correct responses. Now try making against `google` or `cloudflare` dns if its a public domain, or any of your local dns servers.

Comment: I already know the website is running fine, it's just a browser issue. I've accessed it through my mobile device.

Comment: Its not a dns issue with your device. I see that `curl -I http://markhollis.dev/` is returning a response. But in browser i see a 307 redirect to `https`. You can disable this by disabling `hsts` for your website.

Comment: Yep this seems to be it. Thank you Joseph

Comment: https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/ This is what has been giving me the issue.

Comment: Joseph would you mind blurring out the name of my website?